# Eliminate multiple space from a file and modify the original file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Specify the command that removes multiple spaces from a text file, leaving a single space in their place. Extra requirements : Original file to be modified.
Managed to pull out those 3 commands:

```
awk '{$2=$2};1' filename.txt

tr -s '[:space:]' < filename.txt > filename.new && mv filename.new filename.txt  

sed -i 's/\s\+/ /g' filename.txt
```

Not sure if using a 'temporary file' is the best way to do the trick. Is there any more efficient way to do the problem ? Doesn't matter if it is `tr / sed / awk` or anything else, you can post all of them.

Example input:

```
    I'm   just  giving   spaces
```

Output :

```
 I'm just giving spaces
```

Edit: Still looking for more answers

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `ed` over the non-standard `sed -i` (And non-portable RE in your example) if you want to alter the original file:

```
printf "%s\n" '1,$s/[[:space:]]\{2,\}/ /g' w | ed -s filename.txt
```

or with `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\s{2,}/ /g' filename.txt
```

The `{2,}` regular expression construct (`\{2,\}` for POSIX Basic Regular Expressions like `sed` and `ed` use) matches 2 or more of the previous token.

Both of these match any whitespace characters, not just space, because that's how your examples work. If the goal is to only compress multiple spaces, not spaces + tabs, switch out the `[[:space:]]` and `\s` for just a single space.

(Anything that modifies a file "in place", be it `ed`, `sed -i`, `perl -i`, or a regular editor, has a good chance that it's going to be using a temporary file under the hood, by the way. They just handle it for you so you don't have to do it manually like with your `tr` example.)